# Interfacing OpenNI and Media.Capture APIs

Tags: opencv, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, driver, openni

As part of a work project, I am investigating whether it would be possible to create a driver that would bridge OpenNI sensors with the Windows Media.Capture APIs, therefore making any apps that use those APIs compatible with OpenNI sensors.

So far I have extremely little experience with this, but I have concluded that it is possible, although it may be complicated. If anyone could weigh in with any knowledge it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try [OpenNI2 Virtual Webcam - DirectShow filter for OpenNI](http://falahati.net/my-projects/95-openni-2-virtual-webcam-v0-9-directshow-filter-for-openni#.WEs9TqKLSEI)